# Override docker entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile which has the following image.

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 

ENV TINI_VERSION v0.15.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `entrypoint.sh` has some bash commands that are run and the image is built.

Now, I'm using the above image to generate multiple containers using the docker-compose file.

```
services:
  web:
    image: test/tutorials:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  redis:
    image: test/tutorials:latest
```

Each of the web and redis containers needs to have common environment variables that need to be set within them. I don't want to set them in the dockerfile as the image will be built once.

I want to set them when the stack is built. How can common environment variables between 2 containers can be shared? Is there a way to override the `entrypoint.sh` file?

Answer (score -1):

See the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

One possible solution would be to pass through your env var from the host environment:

```
services:
  web:
    image: test/tutorials:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - TINI_VERSION
  redis:
    image: test/tutorials:latest
    environment:
      - TINI_VERSION
```

Then you just set TINI_VERSION in the host env before using `docker-compose run`. There is also the option to set defaults in a `.env` file.

Comment: The downloading and "installation" of tini is part of the Dockerfile build process.  Setting a runtime env variable like this would of course have no effect.